# Bluetooth headset disconnect laptop wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, headphones

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on Dell xps 13. Recently I bought a bluetooth headphone. It automatically connects to laptop bluetooth. It worked 3-4 days perfectly okay. Then I started to have problem that, every now and then my wifi would disconnect automatically while using the headphone. For last couple of days, if I turn on my headphone then my laptop wifi gets disconnected within 3-5 minutes. Even restarting laptop does not work. I have to turn off the headphones and then restart my laptop then it works. Is there any solution for this weird problem.

Comment: The only reliable solution is to use 5 GHz Wi-Fi.